# Random select in with a bias towards certain outcomes (ie 60/40)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Lets say I have 2 lists and I would like to randomly select a winner between the lists but I would like to select the winner from list A 60% of the time and from list B 40% of the time, how can that be done in Google Sheets?

You can randomly select names from a list using this [formula](https://www.sheetaki.com/pick-a-random-name-from-a-long-list-in-google-sheets/)

`INDEX(A2:A, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A2:A)))`

[image]

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Please only use appropriate tags.

Comment: A think an outside the box method might be do-able but I would need to know where the second list resides? Same sheet? Do they follow the same format? Are they dynamic and change or stay the same?

Comment: For future reference, isnt formula for excel & googlesheets basically interchangeable @BigBen?

Comment: @MMsmithH - sometimes, but not all the time. For example, the Google Sheet functions `QUERY` and `REGEXMATCH` do not exist in Excel. There are many more instances where Sheets and Excel are different. Best practice is to use appropriate tags. Also note that for example, `B2:B` is perfectly valid in Google Sheets, but entirely invalid in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing some more information on your setup here is a general formula that does what you're describing:

```
=IF(RAND()<=0.6,INDEX(A2:A, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A2:A))),INDEX(B2:B, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(B2:B))))
```

Essentially it is rolling a random number between 0 and 1. If it is equal to or less than .6 (simulating 60%, since there is a 60% chance it will be less than or equal to .6) it then selects a random name from Column A, otherwise (bottom 40%) it selects from column B.

[image]

You can also replace the "0.6" with **A1** in my example to have the weight be a dynamic number. Changing A1 to 75% for example will then compare the random value against less than or equal to .75.

**EDIT**: Image shows the wrong condition, I was corrected in the sense you want less than or equal to .6 and not greater than, I had the weights flipped.

Comment: You had the idea right, but the implementation wrong. you need to interchange the values in the condition.

Comment: To give bias to column A, you need to check if `rand` is greater or equal to `1 - bias percentage` which equates to 0.4. Since `0.4 - 1` values have 60% change to appear, while 0 - 0.4 has 40% chance, you need to use 0.4 instead

Comment: If you formula is working, then it should be modified to `=IF(RAND()>=0.4,INDEX(A2:A, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A2:A))),INDEX(B2:B, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(B2:B))))`. If using `A1`, then `=IF(RAND()>=(1 - A1),INDEX(A2:A, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A2:A))),INDEX(B2:B, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(B2:B))))`

Comment: Ah I see my error, thank you for pointing that out. I suppose swapping it to `<=.06` would be the same or if hardcoded then use the .4 you mentioned. Updated the post.

Comment: Forgot you could just use lesser than @KevinP. That should work too.